# is it ok to get rid of the path of the folder that is created when installing java 8u60 in windows 8.1?

Tags: java, windows, oracle

Usually when you install the java jdk, you have to then paste the path of the bin folder to the `PATH` environment variable. When I installed it, what I found was that there was a new folder that I did not know about. Here is the path of the folder on my laptop: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

What I notice at the end of the folder (`javapath`) is that there are symbolic links to certain java exes that are in my jdk bin folder. The path for this: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin`

The problem is that the symbolic links only link up to a few java exes and not the whole bin folder (which is why you paste the bin folder in the `PATH` environment variable so you have permanent access to everything and you don't have to set it up each time).

What is also interesting is that the path `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` was put in the `PATH` environment variable when I installed java 8u60.

Can I delete the path `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and replace it with 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin` since `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin` has all the java exes that `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` already has plus more? Would that cause any problems in the future because I plan to use netbeans in the future? If not, can I safely delete the `javapath` folder?

I've only just installed java 8u60 and and I can't execute jar files because there is no link to the bin folder.  I've tried to create `javac.exe` as a symlink and placed it in inside the javapath folder but everytime I type javac in the command prompt I get a message that says that `Jli.dll is missing` when it's actually in the jdk bin folder

I could just set it up each time I use the cmd prompt but that would be redundant and annoying.  I could also just setup `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin` to the PATH environment variable as well and leave `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` alone but I don't know if that would cause any problems.

Ultimately I could just go back to a previous version of java.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change the `PATH` environment variable to be whatever you want it to be, including replacing the `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` value with the `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin` value.

That's what I do, and I've never had trouble with it. Just have to redo it every time you install a new version.

Comment: Great, then would I even need the javapath folder since the jdk is already pointing to those exes?

Comment: No, that's why I *replace* it.